# How to replace a LaTex macro with its argument?

Tags: latex, replace

I want to replace a macro with its argument, that's to say, if I have

```
\newcommand{\foo}{FOO}
```

I want to replace every occurence of `\foo` with its argument `FOO` in a specified region.

I am trying to write a function in order to do this becasue I have to replace more than 100 macros:

```
(defun affil-name ()
  (interactive)

  (setq P0 (make-marker))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (set-marker P0 (point))

  (setq P1 (make-marker))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (search-forward "\\abstract" nil t)
  (previous-line)
  (set-marker P1 (point))

  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region P0 P1)

      (goto-char (point-min))

      (while (search-forward "\\newcommand" nil t)
        (setq pos1 (point-marker))
        (set-marker-insertion-type pos1 t)
        (forward-list)
        (setq pos2 (point-marker))
        (set-marker-insertion-type pos2 t)
        (forward-list)
        (setq pos3 (point-marker))
        (set-marker-insertion-type pos3 t)

        (setq cmd-name (car (extract-rectangle (+ 2 pos1) (- pos2 1))))
        (setq cmd-arg (car (extract-rectangle (+ pos2 1) (- pos3 1))))

        (perform-replace "\"cmd-name\""
                         "\"cmd-arg\"" t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))

        ))))
```

At the end of the loop, value of `cmd-name` and of `cmd-arg` are that of first occurence of `\newcommand` and there are no replacements.

Comment: If elisp is not compulsory here, the programme `de-macro` (in the texlive distribution) is yr friend.

Comment: Do not use `perform-replace`. Heed what its doc string says: `Don’t use this in your own program unless you want to query and set the mark
just as ‘query-replace’ does.  Instead, write a simple loop like this:

  (while (re-search-forward "foo[ \t]+bar" nil t)
    (replace-match "foobar" nil nil))

which will run faster and probably do exactly what you want.`

Comment: @FranBurstall `de-macro` works fine!

Comment: @NickD I generally use `perform-replace` becasuse I am inexpert and so I often use it with query-flag not-nil, so it asks me what to do about each replacement. `replace-match` does not ask anything and it does all replacements all at once (better: I do not know how to set `replace-match` in order to ask me what to do).